# Get all selected items - <mx:CheckBox

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Here is my dataGrid:
How can I get all the selected values of check

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg"
             dataProvider="{listOfItems}" verticalAlign="middle" rowHeight="20" rowCount="30"
              selectable="true" verticalScrollPolicy="on" >
    <mx:columns >
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="col1"                                   
                           dataField="value"
                           headerText="Item Name">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:CheckBox label="{data.vlaue}" paddingLeft="5" />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>

</mx:DataGrid>
```

I have a button below that:

```
<mx:Button x="25"  label="Get Selected Items" width="100" click="getSelItems()" cornerRadius="7" fontSize="12" id="itmSel" />
```

I could find some ways to get the individually selected row by setting `change=""` method, but how to get all the selected items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution I found so far is, to iterate my `dataprovider` checking, if the item is `selected` or not.

And here you go!

```
 var tmpList:ArrayCollection = ArrayCollection(dg.dataProvider);                
 var obj:Object;
 for (var i:int=0; i < tmpList.length; i++)
 {
     if (tmpList[i].Selected == true)
     {
     //Added to my array collection.
     }           
 }
```